# automating runs in databricks

Tags: r, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I am new to the databricks environment and a bit also not much familiar with the
jargon. Here's my question.

I have a jar file called `xx.jar` and a property file with several arguments to run the jar file
called `pp.properties`. The `pp.properties` have several arguments including path to the all the data
required to run the `xx.jar`. These data are stored in my azure storage explorer. This is how I
run a job in the databricks.

1. Created the cluster `mycluster`
2. Create a job and upload `xx.jar` in the section Task by clicking `Set Jar`. In the argument
   section, I give the path to `pp.properties`.
3. Click Run and wait for the job to finish.

I often need to multiple iterations by changing the values in the `pp.properties`, restarting the
cluster and click Run again. I was wondering if there is any way of automating this.
Basically, what I am looking to do is to modify the `pp.properties`, run the jar and repeat this for
n iterations. Any tutorials will also be much appreciated.

Comment: You can run jobs with parameters, if that helps - https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/jobs.html#run-a-job-with-different-parameters

Comment: thanks. So in order to do this, how do I go about. Do I create an R code to automate the change in parameters? I have read that tutorial but it is still not clear

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can acomplish this.

1.Create a notebook which invokes your jar file

2.Parameterize that notebook

```
dbutils.widgets.text("version", "")
val version = dbutils.widgets.get("version")
```

3.Now you can schedule this Notebook to run on particular time or some even based scheduling using Azure DataFactory